# How to add disk partition wizard in MDT 2013?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, deployment, windows-pe

I have a deployment share in MDT 2013, and only use it to install Windows 7 on both new and old PC's and only from a USB drive (offline media).

Is it possible to add a step in a task sequence, so the installation procedure will popup a disk partition wizard, just like when installing Windows 7 from a DVD?

Answer (score 0):

While customizations can be made to the wizard, you're just better off using the commandprompt (F8) to do manipulation to the partitions. Perhaps you could create different task sequences based on what you're tyring to do?